# Neural Network learn limits

Tags: neural-network

I was wondering if there is a way to know the limits of how much can an associative neural network learn.

I want to make a simple network that recognises a few words, maybe even correct them(if i input 'betwen' to know that i meant 'between')

If someone has interesting articles please post them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Multilayer Feed Forward Neural Networks are Universal Aproximators

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem

This means that with a Multilayer Feed Forward Neural Network you can approximate any function f(x) with a empirical function F(x) with an error epsilon.

If your input is a image or a binary matrix with the word "between", then you have to set the input layer with your representation and train with examples with your train and test data.

A simple idea could be clustering the input space with k-means to detect the characters, apply a ocr detection and ensemble the word.

A more complicated method can be developed, such like
http://dl2.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=771584

Comment: I have the characters, the problem is recognising the word, the actual character pattern

Comment: how do you put the characters in the input layer ?

Comment: I haven't created the network yet but i think the input will consist of the actual bits of the characters(5 bits / character) so for 3 characters there will be 15 inputs(perceptrons)

Comment: I dont think that put the bits in the input layers could be a good representation, such representation loses information. If you have the characters in the hand, it doesnt seems like a approximation or classification problem. Anyway you could set a fixed n-input layer with a n-output layer for a specific n-length word. Set your pairs data and train your network. You can use the Matlab or Octave neural network toolbox.